# Infinite sum and partial sum not equal in Wolframalpha

Tags: sequences-and-series, wolfram-alpha

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |(-0.8)^n \theta(n)-(-0.8)^{n-1} \theta(n-1)|$$
$\theta(n) = 1$ for $n \geq 0$ and 0 otherwise.

My attempt to calculate this summation numerically with Python yielded 10. To ensure correctness I tried to verify this answer by calling Wolframalpha within Mathematica with the following query:
`Sum[Abs[UnitStep[n]*(-0.8)^(n) - UnitStep[n-1]*(-0.8)^(n-1)],{n,0,Infinity}]`

It returned 3.6 as primary answer but it's partial sum converged to 10. I am now wondering which answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $10$.

Note that you can rewrite
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |(-0.8)^n \theta(n)-(-0.8)^{n-1} \theta(n-1)|
&= |(-0.8)^0-0|+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |(-0.8)^n \theta(n)-(-0.8)^{n-1} \theta(n-1)|\\
&= 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |(-0.8)^n -(-0.8)^{n-1}  |\\
&= 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |(-0.8)^{n-1}| |(-0.8) -1  |\\
&= 1+1.8\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0.8^{n-1}
= 1+1.8\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0.8^{n}\\
&= 1+1.8\cdot 5 = 1+9\\
&= \boxed{10}
\end{align}$$

*It looks like WolframAlpha really does not like the mix of absolute values and alternating power signs. It has nothing to do with the $\theta(\cdot)$ function itself, [as seen here with `Sum[Abs[(-8/10)^(n) - (-8/10)^(n-1)],{n,1,Infinity}]+1`.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BAbs%5B(-8%2F10)%5E(n)%20-%20(-8%2F10)%5E(n-1)%5D,%7Bn,1,Infinity%7D%5D%2B1)*

*Mathematica, on the other hand, is fine with it.[image]*

Answer (score 0):

Your summation is a geometric series in disguise. Write $r:=0.8$. Plugging in the definition of $\theta(\cdot)$, we see that the $n=0$ term must be handled separately. Your summation is then written
$$
1 + \sum_{n\ge1}|r^n-r^{n-1}|=1+\sum_{n\ge1}|r-1||r|^{n-1}.
$$
The rightmost sum is $9$, by the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Not sure what it means for Wolfram's "primary answer" to be 3.6. Can you show the output?

Comment: Well, just typing it in in wolframalpha gives [3.6 as answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BAbs%5BUnitStep%5Bn%5D*(-0.8)%5E(n)+-+UnitStep%5Bn-1%5D*(-0.8)%5E(n-1)%5D,%7Bn,0,Infinity%7D%5D)

Comment: @vrugtehagel see my answer. Mathematica gives 10 — WolframAlpha must have some weird internal workings.